# cambiar propiedades a valores de un objeto

Tags: javascript, bucle-for, objeto

Tengo una **función** que valida el **parámetro** recibido. Dependiendo el tipo de dato manda un **error**. Cuando es un **objeto** cambia sus **propiedades** a **valores**.

¿*como hacer para que estas queden en el orden en que fueron pasadas*?

Anexo mi código:

```js
function reverseKeys(input) {
  if (typeof input === "number") {
    return "error, input can't be a number"
  }
  if (typeof input === "string") {
    return "error, input can't be an String"
  }
  if (Array.isArray(input)) {
    return "error, input can't be an Array"
  }
  if (typeof input === 'object') {
    var retobj = {};
    for (var key in input) {
      retobj[input[key]] = key;
    }
    return retobj;
  }
}


console.log(reverseKeys(444));

console.log(reverseKeys('hello'));

console.log(reverseKeys([1, 2, 3]));

let res = reverseKeys({
  name: 'santi',
  edad: 22,
  nacionalidad: 'de otro planeta',
  documento: 44444444
});

console.log(res) // { 22: 'edad', 
                      '44444444': 'documento',
                      santi: 'name',     
                      'de otro planeta': 'nacionalidad' 
                    }
```

Comment: Lo que te está mostrando es primero las keys numéricas ordenadas de menor a mayor y luego el resto de keys con strings en el orden en que fueron agregadas al objeto.  Es la forma habitutal de recuperar las keys de un objeto segun parece: https://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_oop-besides-classes.html#_traversal-order-of-properties

Comment: Dicho de otro modo, no lo vas a conseguir.. .aquí te dejo otro artículo diciendo lo mismo pero quizas se entienda mejor: https://www.stefanjudis.com/today-i-learned/property-order-is-predictable-in-javascript-objects-since-es2015/ .... Particularmente he probado creando un json con el orden que tu quieres pero al pasarlo a objeto me ha hecho exactamente lo mismo.

Comment: ok, voy a seguir investigando, por que la consigna lo marca asi, gracias¡

Comment: El orden interno de un objeto no debería determinar el comportamiento del programa. Si es una condición del sistema, puede ser un síntoma de un mal diseño.

Comment: No vas a conseguir lo que buscas trabajando con objetos. Haz una sencilla prueba para comprobarlo: añade a tu objeto una propiedad con una key numérica y comprueba el orden que el intérprete asigna.

Comment: JS no garantiza el orden de objetos de acuerdo con su especificación. al utilizar  metodos que enumeren claves https://lycaeum.dev/en/questions/5525795

Answer (score 1):

También puedes usar [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) para obtener las entradas del objeto (propiedad y valor) e iterar cada uno. Así, podremos crear un nuevo objeto y asignar la propiedad como valor y el valor como propiedad.

```js
function reverseKeys(input) {
  if (typeof input === "number") {
    return "error, input can't be a number"
  }
  if (typeof input === "string") {
    return "error, input can't be an String"
  }
  if (Array.isArray(input)) {
    return "error, input can't be an Array"
  }
  if (typeof input === 'object' && input !== null) {
    const res = {};
    Object.entries(input).forEach(e => {
      const [key, value] = e;
      res[value] = key;
    });
    return res;
    /*
      Forma corta:
      const res = {};
      return [Object.entries(input).forEach(e => res[e[1]] = e[0]), res][1];
    */
  }
}


console.log(reverseKeys(444));
console.log(reverseKeys('hello'));
console.log(reverseKeys([1, 2, 3]));
let res = reverseKeys({
  name: 'santi',
  edad: 22,
  nacionalidad: 'de otro planeta',
  documento: 44444444
});

console.log(res) /* { 22: 'edad', 
                      '44444444': 'documento',
                      santi: 'name',     
                      'de otro planeta': 'nacionalidad' 
                    }*/
```

Comment: el quiere que le retorne el objeto con el mismo orden que lo ingreso pero si invertido

Answer (score 0):

> Tu pregunta ¿como hacer para que estas queden en el orden en que
> fueron pasadas? No es posible con tu objeto  Porque:
> Si necesitas una colección ordenada, la forma recomendada es almacenar
> datos en un Array o usar Map
> No se puede con objetos que tengan claves o propiedades numericas ya que estos no conservan el orden otra respuesta a tu pregunta no tiene en cuenta lo anterior
> Porque

```js
const res={}
function reverseKeys(input) {
  
    Object.entries(input).forEach(e => {
      
      const [key, value] = e;
      res[value] = key;
    });
    return res;
    
  }

let obj={
  name: 'santi',
  edad: 22,
  nacionalidad: 'de otro planeta',
  documento:  44444444
}

const respuesta = reverseKeys(obj);

console.log(respuesta)
```

> Retorna a un objeto que no conserva la ordenacion [ordenacion](https://jsbin.com/fiyitan/edit?html,js,console,output) Ya que JS no
> garantiza el orden de objetos de acuerdo con su especificación si
> se utilizan metodos que enumeren  numericos por ejemplo con un for .. in
> o tratando de asociar clave y valor con el metodo anterior si se usan
> claves o valores ,que sean numericos retorna a un objeto en orden
> distinto al original
> **Se puede apreciar aplicando  Object.entries y luego Object.fromEntries**

```js
const input=  {
  name: 'santi',
  edad: 22,
  nacionalidad: 'de otro planeta',
  documento: 44444444
}  


const inv=Object.entries(input).map(([key,value]) =>[value,key] );
console.log(inv);
const hecho= Object.fromEntries(inv)
console.log(hecho)
/*
[LOG]: [["santi", "name"], [22, "edad"], ["de otro planeta", "nacionalidad"], [44444444, "documento"]] 
[LOG]: {
  "22": "edad",
  "44444444": "documento",
  "santi": "name",
  "de otro planeta": "nacionalidad"
} 


*/
```

```js
{ '22': 'edad',
  '44444444': 'documento',
  santi: 'name',
  'de otro planeta': 'nacionalidad' }
```

Entonces Cambia la estructura  y aplicar un objeto **Map** en el cual se puede iterar las entradas claves y valores en el orden de insercion de la entrada sin importar que sean numericas
ya que poseen caracteristicas distintas
[Objects vs Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)
codigo ejecutable:
[ejemplo con MAP](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=18&ssc=27&pln=1&pc=1#code/PTAEEMAcBsEsGNwDsAmB7UBZKAoU80kBnAF1FiUgFcSBeUUAbz1CXAFsBTALlAHIiyErD4AaFpxTgUvAEyzxDNvFiFwcKTP4pOoNCQBOGGMk4lwYlunhUuSEml4AWF65c4Avgxw%20CxMhQAbpwGwgbYkLRInADuWFAAFACUANw4fqSg7ACeEaD00XERCQDyAEYAVpzwJAB0nPYGsJxECRTUJEmpPgBmaAagCRlkANoA1pzZoqCB6lScALp6PVm5UElMeHhBIWERtURmCbPQ86IT2Uk%20HiwZaNCctdBoAOZtSMGhsOHrLMAAVCw8swGAIhCJ8gA%20fhsLiWBjyKH8STSeHaXT6IygEzRcx8JF8ZSqNgaVGKUBuNwE6y2BoOfE3HwMf7AFgsIA)

```js
// aplicando Map
 const input=  {
  name: 'santi',
  edad: 22,
  nacionalidad: 'de otro planeta',
  documento: 44444444
}  

const exitMap = new Map() ;

const myMap = new Map(Object.entries(input));

for (const [key, value] of myMap) {
 
 exitMap.set(value,key)

}
  console.log(exitMap)
  /*
  Map {
  'santi' => 'name',
  22 => 'edad',
  'de otro planeta' => 'nacionalidad',
  44444444 => 'documento' }


  */
  // aplicado a tu programa 
 const invertirMap=new Map();
function reverseKeys(input) {
  if (typeof input === "number") {
    return "error, input can't be a number"
  }
  if (typeof input === "string") {
    return "error, input can't be an String"
  }
  if (Array.isArray(input)) {
    return "error, input can't be an Array"
  }
  if (typeof input === 'object') {
    for (const [key, value] of myMap) {
 
 exitMap.set(value,key)

}
    return exitMap;
  }
}


console.log(reverseKeys(444));

console.log(reverseKeys('hello'));

console.log(reverseKeys([1, 2, 3]));

let res = reverseKeys({
  name: 'santi',
  edad: 22,
  nacionalidad: 'de otro planeta',
  documento: 44444444
});

console.log(exitMap)
/*

[LOG]: Map (4) {"santi" => "name", 22 => "edad", "de otro planeta" => "nacionalidad", 44444444 => "documento"} 
[LOG]: "error, input can't be a number" 
[LOG]: "error, input can't be an String" 
[LOG]: "error, input can't be an Array" 
[LOG]: Map (4) {"santi" => "name", 22 => "edad", "de otro planeta" => "nacionalidad", 44444444 => "documento"} 
*/
```

[objetos orden](https://dmitripavlutin.com/how-to-iterate-easily-over-object-properties-in-javascript/)
Es mas si quisieramos convertir Map to Object en igual orden con tu objeto tampoco es posible

```js
let obj=Array.from(exitMap).reduce((obj, [key, value]) => (
  Object.assign(obj, { [key]: value }) 
  
), {});
console.log('al convertir Map-->obj no conserva orden :',obj);
/*
al convertir Map-->obj no conserva orden : { '22': 'edad',
  '44444444': 'documento',
  santi: 'name',
  'de otro planeta': 'nacionalidad' }


*/
```

Ni tampoco con Object.fromEntries

```js
const input=  {
  name: 'santi',
  edad: 22,
  nacionalidad: 'de otro planeta',
  documento: 44444444
}  
 const res = {};
    Object.entries(input).forEach(e => {
      const [key, value] = e;
      res[value] = key;
    });
    const object2 = Object.fromEntries(
  Object.entries(input)
  .map(([ key, val ]) => [ val, key ])
);
console.log(object2)
/*
[LOG]: {
  "22": "edad",
  "44444444": "documento",
  "santi": "name",
  "de otro planeta": "nacionalidad"
} 

*/
```

**JS no garantiza el orden de objetos de acuerdo con su especificación.** **al utilizar metodos que enumeren claves** por ejemplo con un for .. in con claves o valores ,que sean **numericos**   Un Objeto si respeta el orden de creacion de propiedades :

```js
var obj = {};
obj.prop1 = "casa";
obj.prop2 = "avion";
console.log(obj)
```

[objetos orden](http://ww16.lycaeum.dev/en/questions/5525795?sub1=20220713-1801-2228-bf81-497514600ff4)
Una forma de ordenar un objeto:

```js
const obj={
    22: 'edad', 
    '44444444': 'documento',
    santi: 'name',     
   'de otro planeta': 'nacionalidad' 
        }
                    
console.log('Object.keys(obj)-->',Object.keys(obj))
// [ '22', '44444444', 'santi', 'de otro planeta' ]
const orden = {};
Object.keys(obj).sort().forEach(function(key) {
  orden[key] = obj[key];
});
console.log(orden);
```

no hay garantias [sin garantias](https://jsbin.com/tukebin/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: El problema no es ese, sino que los indices son numéricos en su caso. prueba tu mismo ejemplo usando numéricos mezclados con los alfanuméricos y veras que sucede lo mismo, es decir, primero se mostraran los numéricos y despues el resto en el orden en que fueron agregados al objeto.

Comment: Asi es es por eso escribi. JS no garantiza el orden .....Si bien se puede ordenar al objeto luego no veo para que lo quiere ordenado?

Comment: Quiere ordenarlo porque alguien se lo ha pedido asi, un profesor o algun iluminado, quizas para hacerle volver loco y darse cuenta que no es posible :-), pero de momento creo que insiste en ello... bueno, pues vale, adelante, sorprendenos!

Comment: ósea que le da prioridad a los números eso entiendo?

Comment: masterguru aclare un poco mas por tu comentario gracias

Comment: @GualbertDev Sí, es lo que decian los enlaces que puse en mis comentarios de tu pregunta (aunque eran en ingles) y basicamente dicen lo siguiente: 1)  En la recuperación de las claves de un objeto primero se muestran las claves numéricas ordenadas de menor a mayor, 2) El resto de claves se muestran tal como fueron agregadas al objeto y 3) Y por último las claves con simbolos tal como fueron agregadas al objeto

Comment: @masterguru
con Map retorna en igual orden al aplicar set lo agregue a la respuesta lo probe en Programiz online y en otros compiladores aunque en la documentacion oficial en el caso de Map dicen conservar el orden en la parte Key orden si aplicaba key y value de la misma forma que antes lo retornaba en un orden no deseado https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map

Comment: @nestdan Bien visto, pero el que hizo la pregunta hablaba de `objeto`, no de `map`, que si bien son parecidos tienen estas diferencias:  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map#objects_vs._maps y por lo tanto no se si le servira o no, el dira.

Comment: por eso la explicacion adicional que no se puede con objetos que tengan claves o propiedades numericas ya que estos no conservan el orden si quiere hacerlo puede pero debe convertirlo a un Map ,Sabes porque si lo ejecuto en cualquier compilador online da lo que pido pero no asi en el compilador de esta pagina?

Comment: sin garantias https://jsbin.com/tukebin/edit?html,js,console,output